# How to morph a fragment into a plug-in?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-fragment

I need to turn Eclipse fragments into plug-ins. Haven't found any wizard to support this.

So I've created a plugin.xml and edited the MANIFEST.MF to look exactly like a plug-in project does. Still, Eclipse somehow detects it's not a plug-in: for example it asks for a Host-plugin.

Also checked .project file, nothing seems to indicate "fragmentness".

**Why I need this:**
Fragments were used for Unit-testing; but they're rather inconvenient: any modification in them triggers a chain of builds, and they block the exporting of individual plug-ins, unless their project is closed.

**Solution**
As Greg suggested it was the 'Fragment-Host:' option that did the trick. And as Rüdiger wrote; the project had to be closed/reopened for eclipse to acknowledge the change.

Comment: Did you delete the `fragment.xml` file?

Comment: Interestingly there's none. The fragments only have a MANIFEST.MF in them. They're used for Unit-testing only.

Comment: I vaguely remember having done that in the past and removing the `Fragment-Host` directive was sufficient. Did you try to close/re-open or delete (without contents) and re-import the project into the workspace so that PDE is forced to refresh its internal for that project?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you convert your test-fragments into plugins?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I edited the question to contain the reason.

Comment: Regarding your motivation for this change: I haven't seen such problems with test fragments. Possibly the reason lies in the way the plug-ins and fragments are set up. [See here for a working example](https://github.com/rherrmann/eclipse-extras), including a test utility plug-in used by fragments. Not sure what 'block exporting individual plug-ins' means though. Feel free to open a separate question if you'd like to try to address the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fragment host is specified in the fragment's `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Fragment-Host: host.plug.in
```

you will need to remove that.

However many fragments rely on code from their host plugin so it may not be possible to just convert the fragment.

Comment: Fragments are used for Unit-testing; they seemed like a good idea for it. But as it turns out, any modification in them triggers a chain of builds, and they block the exporting of individual plug-ins, unless their project is closed.